# Convert list of dates from character to date format

Tags: r, date

I have a vector of dates in character format I need to convert to dates format. Some months are abbreviated and some are not, that's because this list is the result of web scraping. For some reason the following fails to convert "Sept 7" (works for the rest):

```
employ <- c("Jan  5", "Feb  2", "March  9", "April  6", "May  4", "June  1","July  6", "Aug  3", "Sept  7", "Oct  5", "Nov  2", "Dec  7","Jan  4") 
employ2 <- as.Date(employ, format = "%B %d")

#This is what the output of employ2 looks like:
[1] 2016-01-05 2016-02-02 2016-03-09 2016-04-06 2016-05-04 2016-06-01
[7] 2016-07-06 2016-08-03 <NA>       2016-10-05 2016-11-02 2016-12-07
[13] 2016-01-04
```

I thought the problem could be the "t" in Sept, so I took it out using `gsub`. In this case the code fails to convert "Oct 5".

```
employ <- c("Jan  5", "Feb  2", "March  9", "April  6", "May  4", "June  1","July  6", "Aug  3", "Sept  7", "Oct  5", "Nov  2", "Dec  7","Jan  4") 
employ <- gsub("t", "", employ)
employ2 <- as.Date(employ, format = "%B %d")
```

Could someone help to convert the whole list successfully? Thanks very much.

EDIT: please do not respond, clearly the problem is indeed the "t". Just spotted it. Need to figure out a different way to remove the "t" from Sept.

Comment: `as.Date(employ, c(rep('%B %d', 8), '%Bt %d', rep('%B %d', 4)))`

Comment: Or better, `lubridate::parse_date_time(employ, c('%B %d', '%Bt %d'), exact = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have seen, your `gsub` expression failed because it removed additional "t" characters from other strings, such as "Oct".

You can easily modify only the desired string:

```
sub("Sept", "Sep", employ)
```

`sub` is used instead of `gsub` because you need only one substitution per vector entry.

Answer (score 3):

We can only take the first 3 characters from the non-numeric part and then apply `as.Date`

```
as.Date(sub("(.{3}).*(\\d+)", "\\1 \\2", employ), format = '%B %d')
#[1] "2016-01-05" "2016-02-02" "2016-03-09" "2016-04-06" "2016-05-04"
#[6] "2016-06-01" "2016-07-06" "2016-08-03" "2016-09-07" "2016-10-05"
#[11] "2016-11-02" "2016-12-07" "2016-01-04"
```

No need of any external packages and the above output is `Date` class.

Comment: While the accepted answer works for this example, I believe this is the best answer as it will handle **most** cases (as long as the first 3 characters are the correct spelling).

Comment: @Symbolix I agree.  Note to the questioner, you can change the assignment of the check-mark at your will, at any time and for any reason.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree.  @Gracos, it is of course your choice, but this answer is clearly better.

Answer (score 2):

The `lubridate` package's `parse_date_time` can handle a vector of possible formats, but needs `exact = TRUE` set so it interprets the extra `t` as a character, not a token:

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(employ, c('%B %d', '%Bt %d'), exact = TRUE)
#  [1] "2016-01-05 UTC" "2016-02-02 UTC" "2016-03-09 UTC" "2016-04-06 UTC" "2016-05-04 UTC"
#  [6] "2016-06-01 UTC" "2016-07-06 UTC" "2016-08-03 UTC" "2016-09-07 UTC" "2016-10-05 UTC"
# [11] "2016-11-02 UTC" "2016-12-07 UTC" "2016-01-04 UTC"
```